# How do I find out what version of "libosinfo" I am running?

Tags: package-management, libraries

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I tried the `whereis`, `whatis`, `locate`, and `find` commands. I think it is installed. I cannot install it again. I use `apt-get` to install packages. `virt-manager` requires this be at a certain version.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking: what is the output of `dpkg -l | grep libosinfo`?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of packages installable / installed from the repositories, you can use `apt-cache policy` to check whether the package is currently installed and to which version it would be upgraded if you were to run `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
apt-cache policy libosinfo-1.0-0
```

```
user@user-X550CL ~ % apt-cache policy libosinfo-1.0-0
libosinfo-1.0-0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.11-1.1
  Version table:
     0.2.11-1.1 0
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, `libosinfo` isn't a package name, you could use the command below.

```
apt-cache policy ^libosinfo
```

The values for `Installed` and/or `Candidate` shows the version.

---

*Sample output*

```
libosinfo-1.0-0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.11-1.1
  Version table:
     0.2.11-1.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
     0.2.11-0ubuntu1~utopic1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
libosinfo-1.0-0-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.11-1.1
  Version table:
     0.2.11-1.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
     0.2.11-0ubuntu1~utopic1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
libosinfo-1.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.11-1.1
  Version table:
     0.2.11-1.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
     0.2.11-0ubuntu1~utopic1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
libosinfo-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.11-1.1
  Version table:
     0.2.11-1.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
     0.2.11-0ubuntu1~utopic1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @kos ok, you're right. Want to take this in your answer? Then I delete my answer.